# Bootstrap set color of badge dynamically

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, colors

I'm using Django and Bootstrap 4.5 to build a simple web app.

One of my models has a color attribute and I want to visualize it using [bootstrap's badge](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/badge/) by setting the badge's color to the color of the object.

In the documentation it seems like I can only choose from the predefined colors for primary, secondary, etc. Online, I mostly found tips how to overwrite and change the primary color for all badges. Or setting a specific color in a new CSS class.

What I want is to dynamically set the color of the badge according to the Django object's color attribute using Django's HTML templates.

This is what I currently have:

```html
{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ tag.name }}</h1>
    <p>Description: {{ tag.description }}</p>
    <p>Color: <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ tag.color }}</span></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, the badge always has the "secondary" color, but I want it to have `{{ tag.color }}` as color, which may be `#FF0000` for example.

Comment: what is content of tag.color and why wouldn't you just replace secondary with {{tag.color}}

Comment: The content is, eg, `#FF0000`. If I do `<span class="badge {{ tag.color }}">{{ tag.color }}</span>`, it doesn't work. Then I don't see any badge at all. I guess because there is no CSS class `#FF0000`.

Comment: You can use attribute `style` in your `span` : `<span class="badge" style="background-color: {{ tag.color }};">{{ tag.color }}</span>` , if still not work add `!important` property to override bootstraps rule

Comment: @RapSherlock Perfect, that solves my question - thanks! If you add it as answer, I'll accept and upvote. Btw, I didn't need `!important`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use attribute `style` in your `span` :

`<span class="badge" style="background-color: {{ tag.color }};">{{ tag.color }}</span>`

if still not work add `!important` property to override bootstraps rule.